# What Timeout propagates to the orignial Observer?

Tags: rx-java2

If I use the `Timeout` operator on `RxJava2`, what's propagated back to the original `Observer`?

I am creating a Network Request and sending its result as an `Observable`. I want to cancel the Network Request if there's a Timeout. I don't want to use `OnError` to cancel the Network Request, since this will need me to expose the inner variables of the Network Request.

My code is something like this:

```
public Single<String> createSingle() {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        Task<ApiResponse> result = getApiResult();
        Tasks.await(result);
        return result.getResult();
    });
}
```

I know `Single.fromCallable` will propagate any `Exceptions`, I am not sure just how to cancel `result` if there's a `Timeout` or an unsubscription (dispose).

Comment: If you run this Single on a scheduler, you'll get a thread interruption. If you need more explicit cancellation handling, use `Single.create` and register a disposable via `SingleEmitter.setDisposable`.

Comment: What happens if I don't run it in a Scheduler?